# Калькулятор js: на основании объема рассчитать количество машин?

Tags: javascript

Пишу простой калькулятор. В нем нужно рассчитать объем и на основании объема количество машин. Объем я рассчитал, а вот количество машин не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста как рассчитать количество машин если: объем, который помещается в одно машину - до 25 м3, следовательно полученный объем будет кратным 25. Если до 25 кубов - 1 машина, если больше 25 и меньше 50 - 2 машина и тд. Спасибо, в js я еще новичок.

```js
function calculator() {


        const btn = document.getElementById('button');
        const width = document.getElementById('width');
        const percent = document.getElementById('percent');
        const length = document.getElementById('length');
        const height = document.getElementById('height');
        const volume = document.getElementById('volume');
        const auto = document.getElementById('auto');

        btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const totalVolume = (length.value * width.value * height.value) + ((length.value * width.value * height.value) / 100 * percent.value);
            volume.innerHTML = totalVolume.toFixed(2);
        });

}

calculator();
```

```css
.count-calculator__forms{
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.result-calculator__total-content{
  display: flex;
}

.result-calculator__unit{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="count-calculator__forms">
                                    <div class="count-calculator__inputs">
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="height" value="" placeholder="Высота в метрах (В)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="width" value="" placeholder="Ширина в метрах (Ш)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="length" value="" placeholder="Длина в метрах (Д)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="percent" value="" placeholder="Запас в процентах">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="count-calculator__button">
                                        <input type="button" id="button" value="Расчет">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<div class="result-calculator__total-block">
  <div class="result-calculator__text">Объем:</div>
  <div class="result-calculator__total-content">
    <div id="volume" class="result-calculator__volume">0</div>
    <div class="result-calculator__unit">м<span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result-calculator__total-block">
  <div class="result-calculator__text">Количество машин:</div>
  <div class="result-calculator__total-content">
    <div id="auto" class="result-calculator__auto">0</div>
    <div class="result-calculator__unit">шт</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь поможет функция Math.ceil()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следовательно нужно полученный объем в переменной totalVolume поделить на 25 и округлить в большую сторону

Math.ceil(totalVolume/25)

```js
function calculator() {


        const btn = document.getElementById('button');
        const width = document.getElementById('width');
        const percent = document.getElementById('percent');
        const length = document.getElementById('length');
        const height = document.getElementById('height');
        const volume = document.getElementById('volume');
        const auto = document.getElementById('auto');

        btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            const totalVolume = (length.value * width.value * height.value) + ((length.value * width.value * height.value) / 100 * percent.value);
            volume.innerHTML = totalVolume.toFixed(2);
auto.innerHTML = Math.ceil(totalVolume/25);
        });

}

calculator();
```

```css
.count-calculator__forms{
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.result-calculator__total-content{
  display: flex;
}

.result-calculator__unit{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="count-calculator__forms">
                                    <div class="count-calculator__inputs">
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="height" value="" placeholder="Высота в метрах (В)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="width" value="" placeholder="Ширина в метрах (Ш)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="length" value="" placeholder="Длина в метрах (Д)">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="count-calculator__input">
                                            <input data-validate type="text" name="form[]" id="percent" value="" placeholder="Запас в процентах">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="count-calculator__button">
                                        <input type="button" id="button" value="Расчет">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

<div class="result-calculator__total-block">
  <div class="result-calculator__text">Объем:</div>
  <div class="result-calculator__total-content">
    <div id="volume" class="result-calculator__volume">0</div>
    <div class="result-calculator__unit">м<span>3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="result-calculator__total-block">
  <div class="result-calculator__text">Количество машин:</div>
  <div class="result-calculator__total-content">
    <div id="auto" class="result-calculator__auto">0</div>
    <div class="result-calculator__unit">шт</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Забавная задача. Всегда было интересно, как втиснуть машину в "кишку" 1×1×100. По запчастям? Тем не менее, такой алгоритм позволяет управиться с четырьмя машинами. )))

Comment: @UModel тут задача другого плана, нужно не машины в кишку запихнуть, а кишку раскидать по машинам)

Comment: _"от перестановки слагаемых сумма не меняется"_ - стометровая палка будет неприлично выступать из любого кузова, хотя по объёму должна входить однозначно ;-)